# visit for std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, variant-type, visitor-pattern

While solving an online excersise I have written some basic implementation for a `visit` function that works with `std::any`.
The idea is to facilitate the declarative approach for handling `std::any` instead of using `switch` of nested `if else` constructions which are very hard to maintain.

Unfortunatelly, C++ lacks reflection features to deduce a list of underlying types of `std::any` object from a `dispatcher` callable, so one have to provide a template list of underlying types that `std::any` can hold.

Here is an example usage for solving the excercise:

```
int productSum(std::vector<any> array) 
{
    struct
    {
        int operator()(int i, size_t)
        {
            return i;
        }
        
        int operator()(const std::vector<any>& array, size_t level = 1)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (const auto& a : array)
                sum += level * std::get<int>(impl::visit<int,
                                                     std::vector<any>>(*this, a, level + 1));
            return sum;
        }
        
    } dispatcher{}; 

    return dispatcher(array);
}
```

And the implementation itself:

```
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct unique{ using type = T; };

    template <typename... Ts, typename U, typename... Us, template <typename...> class TTupleT>
    struct unique<TTupleT<Ts...>, U, Us...> : 
            std::conditional_t<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<U, Ts>...>, 
                    unique<TTupleT<Ts...>, Us...>, 
                    unique<TTupleT<Ts..., U>, Us...>> 
    {};
    
    template <typename ... T>
    using unique_variant = typename unique<std::variant<>, T...>::type;
    
    // TODO: remove duplicate return values from variant
    template <typename ... DispatchT, typename CallableT, typename ... ArgsT>
    auto visit(CallableT &&callable, const std::any& any, ArgsT &&... args)
    {
        using retval_t = unique_variant<decltype(std::declval<CallableT>()(std::declval<DispatchT>(),
                                                                                                                                            std::declval<ArgsT>()...))...>;
        retval_t ret{};
        
        // typeid can't be used within a fold expression
        (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(any.type() == typeid(DispatchT) && 
                                                                            (ret = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(
                                                                                std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any), 
                                                                                std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...
                                                                            ), 
                                                                             false),0)...};
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I know that most certainly there are problems with type qualifiers, so I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Here's your code in Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/snTPjb6zW )

You have some crazy deep indentation (off the right side of my browser window). Consider switching to "Python-style" indentation, e.g. instead of

```
        // typeid can't be used within a fold expression
        (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(any.type() == typeid(DispatchT) && 
                                                                            (ret = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(
                                                                                std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any), 
                                                                                std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...
                                                                            ), 
                                                                             false),0)...};
        return ret;
```

you could write something like

```
        (void)std::initializer_list<int>{
            (
                any.type() == typeid(DispatchT) &&
                (
                    ret = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(
                        std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any),
                        std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...
                    ),
                    false
                ), 0
            )...
        };
        return ret;
```

Of course this gets way easier with C++11 lambdas. Notice that my indentation style doesn't change:

```
        int dummy[] = {
            [&]() {
                if (any.type() == typeid(DispatchT)) {
                    ret = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(
                        std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any),
                        std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...
                    );
                }
                return 0;
            }() ...
        };
        (void)dummy;
        return ret;
```

---

```
// typeid can't be used within a fold expression
```

That's not true at all. Maybe you initially forgot the parens in `(x && ...)`?

---

Design-wise, it would be easier to use (and also more performant) if you eliminated the dependency on `std::variant`. Instead of accepting a callable that returns `X`-or-`Y`-or-`Z` and then wrapping it up yourself in a `std::variant<X,Y,Z>` which your user then has to *unwrap*, it would be a ton easier to accept a callable that returns `T`, and then return `T` yourself, and let your user just use the `T` that you return. Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3fEbe5s7n

```
    template<class T, class... Us>
    struct all_the_same {
        static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Us> && ...));
        using type = T;
    };
    
    template <class... Ts, class Callable, class... Args>
    auto visit(Callable&& callable, const std::any& any, Args&&... args)
    {
        using R = typename all_the_same<
            decltype(std::declval<Callable>()(std::declval<Ts>(), std::declval<Args>()...))...
        >::type;
        R ret{};
```

---

Your use of `std::declval<DispatchT>()` is questionable. You seem to want each `DispatchT` to be a simple prvalue class type like `std::vector<int>` or `int`, which means that `std::declval<DispatchT>()` would be an xvalue (a `DispatchT&&`). But what you're actually receiving to dispatch on is a `const std::any&`, which means the thing you pull out of it ought to be a `const DispatchT&`. You should adjust your `declval` and your `any_cast` accordingly.

---

Naming-wise, I strongly recommend to use plural names for packs and singular names for non-packs. So your `DispatchT...` should become `DispatchTs...` (or in fact just `Ts...`); your `ArgsT...` should become `Args...`; and so on. This convention makes it easier to reason about pack-expansions at a glance. Compare your

```
            [&]() {
                if (any.type() == typeid(DispatchT)) {
                    ret = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(
                        std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any),
                        std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...
                    );
                }
                return 0;
            }() ...
```

to my preferred

```
            [&]() {
                if (any.type() == typeid(Ts)) {
                    ret = std::forward<Callable>(callable)(
                        std::any_cast<const Ts&>(any),
                        std::forward<Args>(args)...
                    );
                }
                return 0;
            }() ...
```

I claim that mine is easier to read at a glance, because you can "brace-match" the plural nouns with the `...` suffixes, without even knowing what their declarations look like. We *know* `Ts` and `Args` are packs; we know `Callable` is a single type. (We also know that `Callable` is the type of `callable` and `Args...` are the types of `args...`, without being told.)

---

Efficiency-wise, notice that you're not short-circuiting: you're going to evaluate `any.type() == typeid(T)` for *every* `T` in the pack, even if the first one is immediately a match. This is probably fine because `typeid` is super cheap (on Itanium-ABI platforms — I think it's more expensive on Windows), but you *might* consider adding a boolean `has_value` so you can bail early. Alternatively — better? — pull `const auto& type = any.type()` out into a local variable; the compiler *might* be able to tell that it's not modified after that point, and thus short-circuit the comparisons for you.

(The compiler *cannot* inline or combine repeated calls to `any.type()` itself, though, because it's type-erased. The whole point of type-erasure is that the compiler won't be able to statically tell what that function does.)

---

Compare to https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/09/29/oop-visit/

---

EDITED TO REPLY — You commented:

> `R = typename all_the_same` presumes that all the return types must be the same. `std::visit` [...] implies that R must be the same. I just decided to [return a] `std::variant`, so one could chain-pass it to another visitor.

Right, `std::visit` basically takes many-possible-input-types and flattens them down to one-possible-output-type: the "visitor" callable must return the same type for each possible input type. Of course the programmer is *free* to make that single return type something complicated like `std::variant<int, double>` if they want to; but the STL doesn't *force* the programmer into that kind of complication if they don't want it. Compare:

```
std::variant<int, double> v = 42;
double r = std::visit(
    [](auto x) { return double(x + 1); },
    v
);
```

versus what they could have done:

```
std::variant<int, double> v = 42;
std::variant<int, double> r = std::visit(
    [](auto x) { return x + 1; },
    v
);
std::visit([](auto x) { std::cout << x; }, r);  // chaining
```

and versus what the programmer *can* do if they feel like it:

```
std::variant<int, double> v = 42;
std::variant<int, double> r = std::visit(
    [](auto x) { return std::variant<int, double>(x + 1); },
    v
);
std::visit([](auto x) { std::cout << x; }, r);  // chaining
```

With my proposed API for your code,

```
// the programmer can still deal in variants if they _want_ to...
std::any v = 42;
std::variant<int, double> r = impl::visit<int, double>(
    [](auto x) { return std::variant<int, double>(x + 1); },
    v
);
std::visit([](auto x) { std::cout << x; }, r);  // chaining

// ...they're just not _forced_ to.
std::any v = 42;
double r = impl::visit<int, double>(
    [](auto x) { return double(x + 1); },
    v
);
std::cout << r;  // flattening
```

Comment: Using of `R = typename all_the_same` presumes that all the return types must be the same. Documentation for `std::visit` states *1) The value returned by the selected invocation of the visitor.*, but implies that `R` must be the same. I just decided to make it possible to allow multiple return types via a deduced `std::variant`, so one could chain-pass it to another visitor.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to properly deduce the return type of a callable's operator, so I wrote `std::declval<DispatchT>()`. I didn't say it was right. It just worked for the context of the excercise.

Comment: "I wasn't sure how to properly deduce the return type of a callable's operator..." Just add `decltype( )` around the expression you're interested in. Here the expression is `std::forward<CallableT>(callable)(std::any_cast<DispatchT>(any), std::forward<ArgsT>(args))`, so that's what you should use. Except that I still say that `DispatchT` should be `const DispatchT&` so you're not making unnecessary copies.

Comment: You mean `std::any_cast<const Dispatch&>(any)`?

Comment: "You mean `std::any_cast<const Dispatch&>(any)`?" Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! Indeed it is more reasonable to leave the decision on a return type to a programmer, than to provide an enforced convenience.